# Raw Audio from NAudio

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, naudio

I want to record raw audio from WASAPI loopback by NAudio and pipe to FFmpeg for streaming via memory stream. As from this [document](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types), FFmpeg can get input as Raw However, I got result speed at 8~10x!
Here is my code:

```
waveInput = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
waveInput.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>((object sender, WaveInEventArgs e) => 
{
    lock (e.Buffer)
    {
        if (waveInput == null)
            return;
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                memoryStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.Buffer.Length);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
});
waveInput.StartRecording();
```

FFmpeg Arguments:

```
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-f s16le -i pipe:0 -y output.wav");
```

1. Can someone please explain this situation and give me a solution?
2. Should I add Wav header to the Memory Stream then pipe to FFmpeg as Wav format?

**The Working Solution**

```
waveInput = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
waveInput.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>((object sender, WaveInEventArgs e) => 
{
    lock (e.Buffer)
    {
        if (waveInput == null)
            return;
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                memoryStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
});
waveInput.StartRecording();
```

FFMpeg Arguments:

```
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-f f32le -ac 2 -ar 44.1k -i pipe:0 -c:a copy -y output.wav");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you pass the correct waveformat parameters to FFMpeg. You'll to check the [FFmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for details of this. WASAPI capture is going to be stereo IEEE float (32 bit), and probably 44.1kHz or 48kHz. Also you should use `e.BytesRecorded` not `e.Buffer.Length`.

Comment: I used this `-f s32le -i pipe:0 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -sample_fmt s32 -c:a copy -y output.wav`. but got 2x speed. The FFMpeg said: Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono.  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s32le, 44100 Hz, mono, s32, 1411 kb/s

Comment: I changed the above to: `-f s32le -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i pipe:0 -sample_fmt s32 -c:a copy -y output.wav`, and got result: stereo and speed decreasing from 3x to 1x in the first 4 mins, and 1x constantly onward. It brought interference and noise in the entire audio, but I could recognize the sound. What should I do to deal with this? Your information helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think s32 is right. You want to specify float (not sure what the flag is for that). Can't explain the speed increase I'm decrease though - that's very strange

Comment: I though I have tried all the format, and s32le is the closest one. But I was wrong, the correct format is f32le. The resulting audio is just fast a bit for the first 2,3 mins, hard to notice that different. I got stuck at here since yesterday. You saved my life Mark. You are awesome!

Comment: I'm late to the party, but changing your sample format to 48000 got the speed recording normally.

Answer (score 0):

The FFmpeg raw PCM audio demuxers need to be supplied with the proper number of channels (`-channels`, default value is 1) and the sample rate (`-sample_rate`, default value is 44100).

The order of options is important: options immediately before the input get applied to the input, and options immediately before the output get applied to the output.

`ffmpeg` cli example:

```
ffmpeg -f s32le -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 -i pipe:0 -c copy output.wav
```

Your code example:

```
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-y -f s32le -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 -i pipe:0 -c copy output.wav");
```

Comment: I did that just around 30 minutes before your answer, appreciate your help. But my next problem is the output audio is not clear. It has a lot of interference and noise.

Answer (score 0):

Using `WasapiLoopbackCapture`, here is the full command that worked for me without distortion or slowdown:

```
string command = $"-f f32le -channels {wasapiLoopbackCapture.WaveFormat.Channels} -sample_rate {wasapiLoopbackCapture.WaveFormat.SampleRate} -i {pipePrefix}{pipeName} ffmpegtest.wav";
```